# Updating / inserting a nested object React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a JSON object in an array in my Redux store

```
editor: [] 1 item
    0: {} 1 key
      flow {}  3 keys
         id: "1234"
         name: "qaz"
         tasks: [] 5 items
```

What is the best way to update or insert a new *tasks* array

My actions is

```
export function insertTasks(tasks) {
  return {
    type: 'INSERT_TASKS',
    tasks
  };
}
```

And the Reducer is

```
   case 'INSERT_TASKS':
       state[0].flow.tasks = [];
       state[0].flow.tasks = action.tasks;
       return state;
```

I'm passing it the action.type and action tasks correctly and I appear to be updating the tasks array inside my object. But this reducer code just doesn't  feel correct.

When I add a completely new flow my reducer is

```
case 'ADD_FLOW':   
            state = [];
            return [
              ...state, {
               // index: 1,
                flow : action.flow
              }
          ]
```

which feels much better.
So I suppose I looking for the best way to access deep arrays in Redux .

Comment: Use a library, or you will go mad. Many people would recommend `Immutable.js` from FB but there are others, e.g. https://github.com/aearly/icepick is very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue using the spread syntax as deep as you want. For example given this:

```
var o = {
  foo: bar,
  baz: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title',
    description: 'description'
  },
  bang: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

then returning this:

```
return {
  ...o,
  baz: {
    ...o.baz,
    description: 'new description'
  },
  bang: [...o.bang, 4, 5]
};
```

will result in this:

```
{
  foo: bar,
  baz: {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title',
    description: 'new description'
  },
  bang: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Comment: thanks I need to read up a bit more wit spread operator  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid reassigning or mutating anything in your reducers. To achieve this, assuming you only ever have a single item in your state array, you could do something like:

```
case 'INSERT_TASKS':
  return [{
    ...state[0],
    tasks: actions.tasks,
  }];
```

What the spread (`...`) operator is doing here is taking all of the keys from `state[0]` and creating a NEW object with all the same keys currently in `state[0]` after which we are replacing the `tasks` key with the new tasks array.

Comment: thanks I need to read up a bit more wit spread operator  :-)